# I want to print the last line of group using sed

Tags: sed

I have file  which is shown below

```
Section1
    George, 1998-1995
     Peter, 1999-1990
     Simon, 1988-1960
Section2
     Gery,  2019-2015
     John,  1984-1983
     Thomson,  1978-1965
```

When i give **Section1** Expected output is 
Simon, 1988-1960

Like this i have lots of sections. I want to achieve this with sed not using awk.

I tried like this . But it has the line number hard coding. And also it is printing the complete range

```
sed -n '/Section1/,4{p}'
```

Here i could able to remove the hardcoding. But unable to print the last line. And also next section name also coming.

```
sed -n '/Section1/ , /Section./{p}'
```

Comment: do the sections always have 3 lines of indented text? and are you `GNU sed` ?

Comment: No it is not like that. For an example i took it as 3 line. I am using arch linux.

Comment: Could you please review the `sed` answers and let know if anything works for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider using

```
sed -n '/^Section1$/,/^Section[0-9]*$/{:a;h;n;/^Section[0-9]*$/!ba;x;s/^[ \t]*//;p}' file > newfile
```

See [the online demo](https://ideone.com/6V56s4).

**Details**

- `-n` - the switch suppresses default line output mode
- `/^Section1$/,/^Section[0-9]*$/` - a block of lines between a line that is equal to `Section1` and a line that fully matches a `Section` and any 0 or more digits pattern (the next `{...}` group of commands relates to the range matched with this)
- `:a` - sets a label named `a`
- `h` - copies the current line into hold buffer
- `n` - discards the current pattern space value and reads the next line into it
- `/^Section[0-9]*$/!ba` - if the pattern space value does not match the end block line go back to label `a`
- `x` - else, once we get to the last line, the previous one is in hold space, so `x` is used to swap hold and pattern space
- `s/^[ \t]*//`  - remove initial whitespace
- `p` - print the pattern space.

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '$b;N;/\nSection/P;D' file
```

Make a moving window of two lines and print the first line if the second line is begins `Section` and always the last line.

For the last line of a specific section use:

```
sed -n '/^Section1/{:a;h;$!{n;/^\S/!ba};x;s/^\s*//p}' file
```

Comment: This code does not do what is required. It extracts all block last lines, without trimming. OP needs to get the last line of a block when a specific `Section` is passed.

Comment: Could you please let me know why my answer is downvoted? It is working and well-explained... or do I miss anything important?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am sorry you have been downvoted, but not by me. A cursory view of your answer is in essence the same as my second solution however it is not necessary to use a range and it does not cater for the end of file edge case i.e. what would happen if section specified was `Section2`?

Comment: Thanks for feedback and upvote. The range works well even if there is no Section2 as when it is missing it reads to the end of file.

Answer (score 2):

A `gnu awk` solution.

```
awk -v RS='Section' '$1=="1" {print $(NF-1),$NF}' file
Simon, 1988-1960
```

By setting Record Selector to `Section`, `awk` works in block.  Then print the second latest and the latest field of block matching `1`, since `Section` is stripped of.

Comment: thanks for replying. i am looking for a sed solution for this. Is it possible for you to give a sed solution.

Comment: You do not have `awk`?  `sed` may not be the perfect solution for all.  `sed` is more line by line orientated.  `awk` can do a lot more than  `sed`

Comment: Jotne yes i have, my data is little more complex than what is in the example, i masked the data and took an example here. After taking that line i already written a sed code to again parse that line. And entire processing done using sed. I dont want awk only for this.

Comment: I am able to get the range using sed. But unable to get the second last line...

Comment: Then if you post all, we can be able to make a better solution that uses only one command, instead of a mix of thing.

Answer (score -1):

Regex:

```
(Section1)((\n.*,.*)*\n\s*)(?'lastLine'.*)
```

Test [here](https://regex101.com/r/loisLA/1).

I did not understand exactly what you want to do with the result, so I cannot tell you the exact `sed` command.

Comment: The example which i put is a sample data. I have a summary of the data in every section last. I just want to pick the summary. That is the use case. Can you please help me with sed solution

Comment: regex101 is not suitable for command line tools, as sed supports only BRE/ERE flavor of regex, doesn't have features like lookarounds, non-greedy, etc

Comment: @Vipin: "summary" is one thing, "last line" is another thing. I provided a regex which extracts the last line of a section, even if it might not work in `sed`, as stated in one comment. Before creating command lines, we need to understand the needs properly. `sed` is normally used for replacing. What do you want to replace? Why cannot you use another tool?